# How to get Google Directions API to return more than 10 optimized waypoints?

Tags: api, optimization, directions

I'm using the Google Maps Directions API.  When I send a query that has more than 10 waypoints with optimize set to true, the api only returns 10 waypoints.

I read in the docs that using optimization or having more than 10 waypoints requires the "Directions Advanced SKU", but I see know way of specifying this for my project.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Dave